# Number of widgets an application can have in android

Tags: android, widget

Currently i am working on the widget for Android app and the requirement is to have multiple widgets for a single app. I browsed a lot but could not find the answer. Could you please let me know how many widgets(max) can be developed for an android app.

Answer (score 1):

If by "widgets" you mean [app widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview), then your app can have as many different `AppWidgetProvider` classes as you want.